# Correlation matrix using * for significance level

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot, significance

How to plot the Significance codes in a correlation matrix

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Like this:

I've tried the followed code:

```
library(corrplot)
p.matc <- ggcorrplot::cor_pmat(mtcars)
testResc = cor.mtest(mtcars, conf.level = 0.95)
ggcorrplot::ggcorrplot(r, hc.order = FALSE, type = "lower",
                       lab_size = 3,pch.cex =5,digits =1,
                       tl.cex = 12, lab = TRUE,p.mat=p.matc,
                       outline.col = "white",
                       legend.title = "corr",title = "",
                       ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_classic(),
                       colors = c("#E46726", "white", "#6D9EC1"))
```

But I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: What is `r` in your code?

Comment: Where exactly do you want the significance codes placed on that chart?  What does your `R` code provided plot that you don't like?

Comment: I want the significance codes placed on the inside of the boxes with the correlations.
I need to show if the significance is significant at different significance levels.
example: 0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05 and 0.1

Comment: We still need to know what the object `r` is in your code.   I edited another line so that a nonloaded function will run.   But I suspect you are putting the wrong args into the wrong places in your ggcorrplot call as well

Comment: Maybe the [gcorrplot2 package](https://github.com/caijun/ggcorrplot2) might be helpful?